# Grails: domain.each's 'it' can't be coerced to domain's type?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am trying to use a set of "template" objects to populate a harmony relationship on another object, but .each isn't working as Id expect.

Briefly I am modelling a "World" which contains a number of a HouseInstance objects.  Each HouseInstance is associated with another preexisting set of HouseProto objects from which the HouseInstance derives certain features (square feet, # of bedrooms etc.)

so when I create a World, I have a makeHouses routine that creates a HouseInstance for each HouseProto, and assigns the HouseProto to the house instance.

Here is the code:

```
class World {
    static hasMany=[houses: HouseInstance]
    static constraints = {
    }

    void makeHouses() {

        HouseProto.each {
            def hi=new HouseInstance();
            hi.houseProto=   it;
            hi.world=this;

        }
    }
}

class HouseInstance {
    Neighborhood neighborhood

    static belongsTo=[houseProto: HouseProto, world: World]


    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

So I have created several "HouseProto" objects, and then I run the following code:

```
def w= new World()
w.makeHouses()
```

This results it a type coercion error that occurs at the line in makeHouses where I try to assign the HouseProto object to the HouseInstance object.

```
 hi.houseProto=   it;
```

'it' should of course be a HouseProto instance because it is instantiated by the each method on the Domain class.  Nevertheless I get the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.Class] to required type [com.grapevine.negotiator2.HouseProto] for property 'houseProto': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:306)
```

It seems to be telling me that 'it' is not a HouseProto, but simply a java.lang.Class of not particular type which can't be coerced to a HouseProto.  I don't understand how that is possible (or how to fix.)

Comment: Very basic thing that you are trying to iterate a class and not a collection of class objects.

Answer (score 0):

`HouseProto` is your domain class. I suppose you need a list of `HouseProto` instances, right? Then:

```
HouseProto.list().collect {
    new HouseInstance(houseProto:it, world:this)
}
```

I changed `each` to `collect` to return a list of `HouseInstance`.

Comment: That's interesting but what I want to know is why my code is eroding.

Comment: @user1023110 Maybe I don't understand your question, sorry. `it` in your `each` is a `java.lang.Class` because you are not iterating over an instances list of `HouseProto` but a domain class which is a `java.lang.Class` and `hi.houseProto` needs an instance of `HouseProto` not the `HouseProto` class. That's why you get `Cannot convert value of type` error.

Comment: Yeah, that was a mistake.  I should have been using HouseProto.findAll().each

Answer (score 0):

Simple mistake.  I should have iterated HouseProto.findAll().each or something like that.  Not just HouseProto.each().